# Search by string date mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to run query that return a rows by range of dates.
the dates are saved in a string format like "22/11/2017"
i try to used in `str_to_date` but its not work so good.
my query :

```
SELECT Activities.Date AS 'dates'  FROM Attendance
                           INNER JOIN Activities ON Activities.ID=Attendance.ActivitiesID
                           INNER JOIN Groups ON Activities.GroupID=Groups.ID
                           INNER JOIN Projects ON Projects.ID=Groups.ProjectID
                           WHERE Attendance.Attendance <>'' AND Projects.ID=16 AND  (str_to_date(Activities.Date,'%d/%m/%Y')>="01/11/2017" AND str_to_date(Activities.Date,'%d/%m/%Y')<='30/11/2017') GROUP BY Activities.Date
                            ORDER BY Groups.Name
```

The result :

```
'24/09/2017','24/10/2017','24/11/2017','24/12/2017','25/09/2017','25/10/2017,..
```

Comment: _the dates are saved in a string_ if you can modify the schema, I highly suggest to convert column from varchar to date, it will simplify your life a lot and also be quicker on queries by date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Select STR_TO_DATE(string_date_col, '%d/%m/%y') FROM table_name...
```

In your case, you are converting it into date but you are again comparing it with string, you need to convert all the strings to date format so that it can have a valid comparison so it should be

```
(str_to_date(Activities.Date,'%d/%m/%Y')>=str_to_date("01/11/2017",'%d/%m/%Y')
```

instead of

```
(str_to_date(Activities.Date,'%d/%m/%Y')>="01/11/2017"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL wild card like `Activities.Date LIKE "%11/2017"` to get all the activities recorded in the month of november 2017. With that your query should be:

```
SELECT Activities.Date AS 'dates'  FROM Attendance
                       INNER JOIN Activities ON Activities.ID=Attendance.ActivitiesID
                       INNER JOIN Groups ON Activities.GroupID=Groups.ID
                       INNER JOIN Projects ON Projects.ID=Groups.ProjectID
                       WHERE Attendance.Attendance <>'' AND Projects.ID=16 AND Activities.Date LIKE "%11/2017" GROUP BY Activities.Date
                        ORDER BY Groups.Name
```

Comment: Febraury will be like `"%02/2017"`. So yes it will work ;)